# How to position a view relative to one of its child views?

Tags: swiftui

Absolute positioning of a view in its parent is easy using the `.position(x:y:)` and related methods. However, what I want to do is position the view so that the center of one of the view’s child views is at the desired absolute position within the parent (such that the frame/position of the view (not child view) will be moved to achieve this).

See the example below. What I would like to achieve is having the red circle’s center be at position x: 67, y: 45 (which would make the red circle end up on top of the green square) and not the center of the `AnnotationView`. Ideally the solution would allow me to pick any child view (at any size and position) to act as the view to center on (with code changes of course).

I’ve tried various solutions using `GeometryReader` with custom coordinate spaces and view preferences, but haven’t found a solution.
[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let childPosition: CGPoint
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.yellow)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .overlay(
                ZStack {
                    // Only here as a visual aid for this question
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.green)
                        .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                        .position(childPosition)
                    
                    AnnotationView(position: childPosition)
                        .position(childPosition) // Position here needs to be updated so that the center of the red circle is at the childPosition
                }
            )
    }
}

struct AnnotationView: View {
    let position: CGPoint
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("(\(Int(position.x)), \(Int(position.y)))")
            
            Circle()
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(width: 7, height: 7)
        }
    }
}

struct _Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(childPosition: CGPoint(x: 67, y: 45))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a generic solution that combines use of alignment guides and @Shawn’s trick of using `.background()`. No major modifications are required on the view (see * below) other than adding the view modifier `.offsetCenterWithPositionCenteringAlignment()` and then adding the `.centerOnWithPositionCenteringAlignment()` modifier to the child view you want to center on. This will work for any view even if the elements change size such as text with dynamic type.

It works by wrapping your view in a 1 x 1 clear square, and then presents your view as the background. Custom alignment guides are set up such that the child view that’s specified using `.centerOnWithPositionCenteringAlignment()` will end up being centered in the middle of the 1 x 1 square. Then the parent view will position your view using the 1 x 1 square (since your view is in the background). This will make your view appear to be centered on the specified child view.

*One issue with this is that it can end up constraining the size of your view such that view elements like text will require the `fixedSize()` modifier.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let childPosition: CGPoint
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.yellow)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .overlay(
                ZStack {
                    // Only here as a visual aid for this question
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.green)
                        .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                        .position(childPosition)
                    
                    AnnotationView(position: childPosition)
                        .position(childPosition) // Position here needs to be updated so that the center of the red circle is at the childPosition
                }
            )
    }
}

struct AnnotationView: View {
    let position: CGPoint
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("(\(Int(position.x)), \(Int(position.y)))")
                .fixedSize()
            
            Circle()
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(width: 7, height: 7)
                .centerOnWithPositionCenteringAlignment()
        }
        .offsetCenterWithPositionCenteringAlignment()
    }
}

extension View {
    func offsetCenterWithPositionCenteringAlignment() -> some View {
        Color.clear
            .frame(width: 1, height: 1)
            .background(alignment: .positionCenteringAlignment) {
                self
            }
    }
    
    func alignmentGuide(_ g: Alignment, verticalValue: @escaping (ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat, horizontalValue: @escaping (ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat) -> some View {
        self
            .alignmentGuide(g.vertical, computeValue: verticalValue)
            .alignmentGuide(g.horizontal, computeValue: horizontalValue)
    }
    
    func centerOnWithPositionCenteringAlignment() -> some View {
        self.alignmentGuide(.positionCenteringAlignment) {
            $0[VerticalAlignment.center]
        } horizontalValue: {
            $0[HorizontalAlignment.center]
        }
    }
}

extension Alignment {
    static let positionCenteringAlignment = Alignment(horizontal: .positionCenteringAlignmentGuide, vertical: .positionCenteringAlignmentGuide)
}

extension VerticalAlignment {
    private struct PositionCenteringAlignment: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in context: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            context[VerticalAlignment.center]
        }
    }
    
    static let positionCenteringAlignmentGuide = VerticalAlignment(PositionCenteringAlignment.self)
}

extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private struct PositionCenteringAlignment: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in context: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            context[HorizontalAlignment.center]
        }
    }
    
    static let positionCenteringAlignmentGuide = HorizontalAlignment(PositionCenteringAlignment.self)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sample code you've given is really close to solving it already. If you notice from your screenshot, `AnnotationView` as a whole is centered over the green square. With that in mind, one way to reach your goal is by moving the Text element from `AnnotationView` into the background.

```
struct AnnotationView: View {
    @ScaledMetric var offset = 20
    let position: CGPoint

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
        .fill(.red)
        .frame(width: 7, height: 7)
        .background(
            Text("(\(Int(position.x)), \(Int(position.y)))")
            .fixedSize()
            .offset(CGSize(width: 0, height: -offset))
        )
    }
}
```

Position will ignore the Text element if it is in the background. We can then use the `.offset` modifier to reposition it above the dot as before and the `.fixedSize` modifier to ensure all text is visible. This method doesn't require any changes to your `ContentView`.

Edit: Made the offset a [@ScaledMetric](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-scaledmetric-property-wrapper) to adjust with the user's Dynamic Type Settings.

Comment: Thanks! I like how that does enable the positioning to be centered on the specific child view (red dot) no matter its shape or size. However, I was hoping to find a solution that wouldn’t require hardcoding values (eg the offset) based on assuming that the view won’t change in the future. For example, if someone needs to increase the font size for accessibility reasons then the spacing between the dot and text won’t be correct. Or if in the future we allow the user to change the size of the dot dynamically, then the text might get covered.

Comment: @ospr This solution could easily be made dynamic based on your specific needs. The offset could be a ScaledMetric to adapt with the user's dynamic size preferences, a multiple of the dot size, or some combination of both calculated inside of .onAppear. I've updated my answer to scale with the user's dynamic size settings.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Using ScaledMetric would help in that situation, but it feels a bit like rather than letting the layout system do a lot of the heavy lifting for you you’re having to manage and fight with it (which could lead to unexpected bugs if not all of the cases are handled and might not scale as view complexity grows). Using part of your code, I think I was able to come up with a more generic solution (see answer) which makes use of the layout system to achieve the desired goal (although still not quite perfect as described in the answer).

Comment: Will definitely give your answer a 1 up since it has been helpful.